# BlackBerry - RadioButtonField, hide border on select

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, focus, radio-button, border

I have a screen with two RadioButtonField objects. By default, the first RadioButtonField shows a rectangle around it to show its selected, and the rectangle moves if you change the selection to the other RadioButtonField or other buttons and textboxes on the page. What I would like to know is...is there a way to hide this border that shows the selection/border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you in 4.6 and higher, try to [setBorder()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setBorder%28net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Border%29) without edges:

[alt text http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/672/rbnoborder.jpg](http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/672/rbnoborder.jpg)

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {  
    EditField editField = new EditField("edit field", "text");
    RadioButtonGroup rbGroup = new RadioButtonGroup();
    RadioButtonField rbField = new RadioButtonField("First field");
    RadioButtonField rbField2 = new RadioButtonField("Second field");
    ButtonField buttonField = new ButtonField("button");
    Border invisibleBorder = 
        BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0,0,0,0));     
    public Scr() {
        add(editField);
        rbGroup.add(rbField);
        rbGroup.add(rbField2);
        add(rbField);
        add(rbField2);      
        add(buttonField);       
        editField.setBorder(invisibleBorder);
        rbField.setBorder(invisibleBorder);
        rbField2.setBorder(invisibleBorder);        
        buttonField.setBorder(invisibleBorder);             
    }
}
```

If you in 4.5 and lower, try to override [drawFocus()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#drawFocus%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics,%20boolean%29) and leave it empty:

[alt text http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/672/rbnoborder.jpg](http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/672/rbnoborder.jpg)

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    EditField editField = new EditField("edit field", "text") {
        protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
        }
    };
    RadioButtonGroup rbGroup = new RadioButtonGroup();
    RadioButtonField rbField = new RadioButtonField("First field") {
        protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
        }
    };
    RadioButtonField rbField2 = new RadioButtonField("Second field") {
        protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
        }
    };
    ButtonField buttonField = new ButtonField("button") {
        protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
        }
    };

    public Scr() {
        add(editField);
        rbGroup.add(rbField);
        rbGroup.add(rbField2);
        add(rbField);
        add(rbField2);
        add(buttonField);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me to discover that the border can also be changed only for a specific state, eg: rbField.setBorder(Field.VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS, invisibleBorder);

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the [drawFocus](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#drawFocus) method of the object, by extending it.

Comment: Already tried that, and did not call super.drawFocus but it didn't remove the border for me.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see why, from Max's answer that your solution isn't working for me. I am trying to compile against 4.7 extending drawFocus is only the solution for 4.6 and below. I probably should have mentioned my JDE version in my post!